# AI Bot programming environment

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bots

I am just finishing up an Artificial Intelligence course where, as part of the assignments, I was able to program bot in a multi-player environment ([BZFlags](http://bzflag.org/)).
What I was able to do was to program the bot to interface with the world and play capture the flag against other bots or even humans.

What I would like to know is, **what other environments are out there where I could do the same thing (programming bots for a game or in a specialized environment)?**

I was able to do this with BZFlags because they ad an API provided so that I could send commands to my bots and find out information about the world around them.

Comment: out of curiosity, what language was your program written in?

Comment: C++, simply because the interface to the game server was already written in C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) and [NRobot](http://home.gna.org/nrobot/).

In RoboCode, you use Java to program your Robot's AI, and then unleash him against other Robots and see how he does.  NRobot is the .NET version of a very similar idea.

Answer (score 4):

[RobotBASIC](http://www.robotbasic.org/) is similar.

Comment: I don't want to build a game, I would like to just play around with an existing gaming environment and program my bots to play to intelligently.

Answer (score 2):

another, possibly interesting thing to look at is [SoccerFun](http://www.cs.ru.nl/P.Achten/SoccerFun/SoccerFun.html) but it is in Haskell and it's about programming cooperative bots

Answer (score 0):

[How I Built a Working Poker Bot](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-poker-bot) describes some of the process of building a poker bot.  The author states "**And if I can build one, well. Anybody can build one.**"  I found this by way of [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118919/what-is-the-strangestweirdest-program-youve-ever-made#119447).